# Changing DNS records to point subdomain to new IP

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a shared hosting account at `http://shared.webfactional.com/`.

I have another website at `www.example.com`. I want to be able to go to `www.shared.example.com/` and load the stuff from my shared hosting account. I do not mean a url redirection, as the end url will be at `www.shared.example.com`. What do I need to do in the DNS A or CNAME records to get the shared hosting account on this specific domain extension with the `new-site` string prepended?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on a shared hosting account, you are going to need to contact you provider and follow their instructions to get things setup. They'll need to setup your new hostname as an alias or similar to your current domain.